# Why doesn't ignored tags work on Opera Mini?

Tags: support, tags, ignored-tags, opera-mini

<sub>I'm sure there is a duplicate somewhere. Please point me to it if there is.</sub>

Browsing with my mobile phone with an Opera Mini browser, I added tags to my ignore list and refreshed the page, but questions with those tags were still there.

Is that supposed to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They should be faded out. Ignored question will only truly disappear if you tick the `Hide Ignored Tags` button on the Prefs tab in your User Profile.

Comment: Okay - that explains a few things. I'm using a mobile browser, so that's probably why it isn't faded.

Answer (score 0):

You could go to your profile, the *prefs* tab, and click *Hide Ignored Tags*.

That might work on your mobile browser, but it would be a very good idea to specify which one.

Safari? Opera Mini? Opera Mobile? Firefox Mobile?

Comment: I have Opera Mini.

Comment: @George: then this might work, as the JavaScript is processed serverside.